# Prestashop add product to cart strange quantity

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add a product to PrestaShop cart programmatically. I use the `updateQty()` together with the quantity to update and the product id. However when I add the product to cart, it automatically adds 10 quantities of product. Am I using it the wrong way around?

I am using the `actionCartSave` hook in my custom module.

I have tried this:

```
public function hookActionCartSave($params){
    $cart = $params['cart'];
    $cart->updateQty(1, 408);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hookActionCartSave` is called one more time at once. So every time that it will be called you increase of 1 the quantity in the cart of that product (in your case with id 408), maybe it is called 10 times in your case.

To answer to your problem, we have to check if the product is already in the cart, try this snippet:

```
public function hookActionCartSave($params)
{
    $cart = $params['cart']; // Get the cart object
    if(Validate::isLoadedObject($cart)){ // Check if the cart is a valid object
        if(!$cart->containsProduct(408)){ // Check if our product is already in cart
            $cart->updateQty(1, 408); // Add our product to cart
        }
    }
}
```

Adapts the code to your needs ;)

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm, thank you very much :-). Though it actually got me thinking: What is the procedure to increase(qty) a product that is all ready in the cart? Dunno if that is another question :-)

Comment: Hehe, great question, at the moment I don't have a quick answer for you :P but I guess you can find the solution by yourself ;)